# Ubuntu Software Center buy button doesn't work

Tags: software-center

I just bought the new Humble Bundle, and I want to play the games on Ubuntu, but whenever I click on "Download with Ubuntu" the software center comes up on the page of the game, but whenever I click on the buy button it comes up with this message:
Unable to load page

> Problem occurred while loading the URL
>   https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/tos/plain/ Cannot resolve proxy hostname
>   ()

And so I can't buy the games. Could someone please help me?
Thank you for reading, ~Joel

Answer (score 1):

This seems a problem with **Firefox integration with Software Center**. I also have come across it many times. Yesterday, while using an accounting software-"Manager", same message was appeared as it also uses browser integration.

It worked for me when I copied the URL "http://......." and pasted in Firefox’s address bar, hence further process will happen in Firefox's window. But I am not sure if it works with Ubuntu Payment service. You can try with any application with 'zero' price, if it works, then I suggest to proceed for transaction.

Problem occurred in Ubuntu 12.04